# Where is UINavigationItem disappearing to when refactoring views to storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, uinavigationitem

I'm rewriting an Obj-C project using Swift 4 / Xcode 9.2

I have a large storyboard that I am breaking down into multiple storyboards. I did this previously without any issues. If I refactored a few views to their own storyboard then the views took the navigation item with them. now they disappear...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[[image: CS [6]]

[image]
My questions are ...

Is this an Xcode bug? or a new feature?

Obviously you can work around this as I have shown in the pictures but is there a way to stop the vanishing from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way it's always been. In your storyboard, if a view controller is *not* a child of a navigation controller via root view controller or push segues, then by default no navigation bar is shown in the storyboard. You can force it on, though, by going to the Simulated Metrics section of the Attributes Inspector tab and selecting one of the navigation bar options for "Top Bar".

Comment: Thanks Tyler. Perhaps I'm misremembering what happened previously but I'm fairly certain it didn't happen that way when i refactored views into new storyboards with Xcode 8.The simulated metrics trick worked and allowed a navigationItem to be added and be visible on the ViewController

Answer (score 1):

Your view controller is no longer a child of a navigation controller, so it no longer *automatically* has a navigation item. If you need it to have a navigation item, drag a Navigation Item from the Object Library onto it. You will then be able to give the navigation item a title, and drag buttons and so forth onto the navigation item.