# Refactoring storyboard, results in navigation controller dependent scene navigation items to disappear but still working

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, xcode-storyboard, scene

I use Xcode 9.2 and iOS 10.x.
I would like to refactor my large main storyboard to smaller ones.
My initial login scene is embedded in a *navigation controller*, so **all other consequating scenes are in the navigation stack** and I have created *view controller titles* and *navigation bar buttons* to them.

After refactoring a branch of my scenes that are related to staff management to a new storyboard, everything has been moved correctly and links between storyboards created and the application still working as expected. I did the refactoring using Editor-->Refactor to Storyboard...

However, when you go to the editor of the new Staff storyboard you will notice that all navigation headers and buttons are missing, although working. For example, in the first scene I have a title and in the 2nd screen of the stack I have several nav bar items.  All of these are missing in editor but appear when I run my application.

Does anybody knows how I can make navigation items visible again, in my new Staff storyboard, in order to edit them further e.g. add new buttons etc. ?
Is there any fix to all of this or is it a normal feature of Interface Builder/Xcode?

An oversimplified "version" of this issue could be recreated as follows:
 1. you have just one view controller A embedded in a Navigation Controller.
 2. you add navigation items / nav bar buttons in the navigation bar
 3. you remove the navigation controller and as a result you loose in the editor any buttons

Comment: One workaround or possible solution that I found is the use of Attributes Inspector --> Simulated Metrics on the initial View Controller of the Staff storyboard.  Top Bar was set by default to Inferred. By setting Top Bar = Transclucent Navigation Bar I can see now all the navigation bar items in all the View Controllers of the stack inside the Storyboard.

Comment: If Simulated metrics is a solution then this could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531564/where-is-uinavigationitem-disappearing-to-when-refactoring-views-to-storyboard?rq=1 . What is not clear to me related to this approach, is whether changing Simulated metrics has an impact to the runtime of the application according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279379/what-impact-does-simulated-metrics-have .